# getInt(string) from asset

Tags: java, android, assets

In my project I had some music in raw . I can read them and play them easily in this way :

```
 Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
        SongInfo info = new SongInfo();
        try {
            String name = fields[i].getName();
            if (!name.equals("ringtones")) {                    info.setFileName(name + ".mp3");
                info.setFavorite(pref.getString(info.getFileName()));
                int audioResource = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(name);
                info.setAudioResource(audioResource);

}
             info.setName(name);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO: handle exception

            Log.e("LOG", "Error: " + e.getMessage());

        }

        listSong.add(info);
```

NOW I PUT MY MUSIC IN ASSET FOLDER ,and change my code like this (i read them from ASSET):

```
String[] files = context.getAssets().list("mp3");
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length ; i++) {
        SongInfo info = new SongInfo();
        String name = files[i];
        name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 4);

        if (!name.equals("ringtones")) {
            info.setFileName(name);    
            info.setFavorite(pref.getString(info.getFileName()));              
      //int audioResource = R.raw.class.getField(name).getInt(name);
            //info.setAudioResource(audioResource );
        }
        listSong.add(info);
    }
```

now I can read them from asset corretly ,but just for playing them ,I need int audioResource.(the lines that are comment)
How to access to this int audioResource?
How to getInt(name) from asset?
any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you keep your music in assets if it works in raw?

Comment: From assets you cannot get such resource. You can however open an input stream from it. So look if you can use the stream instead.